# Sailsjs with multiple conditions in 'where' statement not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, google-cloud-sql, waterline

I am developing a nodejs project and using sailsjs for db. I need to have multiple conditions part of 'where' statement, the puzzling part is that my code works when running locally but when I push to live (GAE-mysql) it doesn't work anymore. Locally mysql is not setup so locally mysql is not used, and as mentioned locally it works, how could mysql change anything regarding this, is it possible that sailsjs cannot handle converting multiple conditions to mysql?

Code:

```
Pro.find()
            .where({ 
                and:[
                    {status:{'!':'REMOVED'}}, 
                    {ex_date: {'>=': current_date}}
                ]})
            .populate('user_p')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Example code:

```
Prop.find()
    .where({p : {'>=': lowerl}},{p : {'<=': upperl}})
    .where({be : {'>=': becntr}})
```